# Sirikit and parent app communication in ios 10 : Handoff

Tags: swift, ios10, handoff, sirikit

I am using Sirikit to integrate with my payment domain app where I need to interact with the app. I read Apple documentation, they asked to use common frameworks.
Is it possible to use handoff? if yes then how? 
How can I call the other viewController which is in parent app from sirikit?

I will really appreciate for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [SiriKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ResolvingandHandlingIntents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH5-SW1),

To use handoff, You can create intent response object with `NSUserActivity` object. While creating `NSUserActivity` object assign userInfo property to appropriate object that you want,

```
let userActivity = NSUserActivity()
userActivity.userInfo = ["myKey": myAnyObject]
```

You will get this `NSUserActivity` object in parent application AppDelegate,

```
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Swift.Void) -> Bool
```

Here you can get `userInfo` object which you can compare as per your requirement and call appropriate viewController.

Comment: Thanks Dhawal for your explanation. I also tried the same. But, the handoff is not happening seamlessly. It is giving "open app" button. once you click the button, it will open the app.

Comment: @Dhawal.. The SiriKit sample code is saying "Page Not Found".  How to fetch data from parent application from the IntentUI extension with out navigating?

Answer (score 1):

Every user activity object needs a type and we need to define those types in the

> info.plist of the application

For Eg.

```
let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "uaType")
userActivity.title = "uaTitle"
userActivity.userInfo = ["uaKey": "uaValue"]
```

You can now access this activity object in `AppDelegate` as follows

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        switch userActivity.activityType {
        case "uaType": 
        //Write your logic to access uaKey & uaValue here
        return true
        default: return false
        }
}
```