# SiriKit can't send message in my project

Tags: message, ios10, sirikit

I want to use SiriKit send a message, but I found that the whole event at the end of the handler method, will not continue in the main app. In my project, sending a message module depends on many things, is not simple abstract into a framework, so the SiriKit can't realize my demand, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Sirikit allows to handle voice in framework. When you say "Send message to Thornaci using 'myApp'." it handle it in intent and you can listen it with Handoff in mainApp. [You can check here for Handoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417719/sirikit-and-parent-app-communication-in-ios-10-handoff)

Answer (score 0):

First, u should add intent extension in your app

After u builded your app, u should check your phone setting--siri--app support--yourapp permission

Then u can try "Send message to XX on myApp" in siri test.